# Is there any way to skip ssl validation on bosh-cli v2?

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

Is there any way to skip ssl validation on bosh-cli v 2.0 like bosh 1.0:

```
$ bosh target http://.... --skip-ssl-validation
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of skipping ssl validation you can set --ca-cert option for self-signed bosh certs (to the issuing CA cert):

```
bosh-cli help |grep ca-cert
    --ca-cert=         Director CA certificate path or value [$BOSH_CA_CERT]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. now i got this: 
```    
>    Fetching info:
>      Performing request GET 'https://xxxxx.net:25555/info':
>        Performing GET request:
>          Retry: Get https://xxxxx:25555/info: x509: certificate is valid for *, not xxxxx.net
>    Exit code 1

Comment: How did you create the certs?

You need to have a subjectAltName (or CN) field matching your domain name.

Answer (score -3):

No, there is no way and no plans to implement this.

SSL validation is important security procedure. Ability to skip it is dangerous anti-pattern.

Comment: I agree it is dangerous in production. but i only need test environment at this time. I think security strategy is user's decision.